# What does "//" (forward slash, forward slash) do in a PHP pathname?

Tags: php, scripting, relative-path

I'm looking at a bit of script and I'm not sure what the "//" does.

```
$ResultsFolder = "./" . "Results";
$CompanyFolder = $ResultsFolder."//".$CompanyName;
```

Comment: it is not actually a PHP, but a pathname. And a pathname belongs to filesystem.

Comment: In this case, it makes the resulting code less readable. Nothing more (probably).

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't do anything `/./` and `//` mean the same thing than `/`

Comment: Possibly it was adapted from the windows version "\\" at some stage, which is needed to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Beware: it doesn't do anything in a filesystem, but it will in browsers.

Example: your script is hosted at https://dummy.tld/folder/file.php, and containing the following:

```
<a href="[url, see below]">Link</a>
```

[url] could be:

```
example.txt -> https://dummy.tld/folder/example.txt
/example.txt -> https://dummy.tld/example.txt
//example.txt -> https://example.txt/
```

Note: this behaviour applies only if it starts with '//something', if you're using './/something', it will resolve to 'something'.

Comment: In this case the path prefix is `./Results//…`.

Comment: This will work only if the // is at the beginning of your string ! Not the case here.